# Translating custom type from F# to Scala

Tags: scala, f#

I started to learn Scala out of interest, and I decided that I want to translate Scott Wlaschin's [parser combinators](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/parser/) package from F# to Scala, so the stuff would really settle in.
The whole point of Scott's package is to use monads practically everywhere, so I'm also looking at this as a chance to understand monads even further.

In one of the early slides, he defines the type `type Parser<'a> = Parser of (string -> Result<'a * string>)`, where:

```
type Result<'a> = 
| Success of 'a
| Failure of string
```

The subtle thing in this definition is the coupling between `'a` on both sides of the equation of `Parser<'a>`.

In any case, how can I translate the above statements to Scala, while preserving the subtlety that I mentioned?

For the first one I thought of this:

```
type ParserType[T] = String => Result[(T, String)]
```

and for the second one (which is a choice type) I thought of this:

```
sealed trait Result[T]
case class Success[T](result: T) extends Result[T]
case class Failure[T](msg: String) extends Result[T]
```

but, it seems stupid to use `[T]` in `Failure`, since it doesn't use `T` at all. Is there some syntax which can more closely resemble the F# syntax?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the new right biased `Either` in Scala 2.12 (baring that, there was a `Xor` data type in the Cats lib.) However, to answer your question directly:

```
sealed trait Result[+T]
case class Success[T](result: T) extends Result[T]
case class Failure(msg: String) extends Result[Nothing]
```

this takes advantage of type covariance. Any `Failure` here can be used with any `Success`. Note, this doesn't handle `map` or `flatMap` concerns.

Comment: Why would you want to take advantage of type covariance?

Comment: In this case anything that accepts a type of `Success[Int]` will also take an instance of `Failure`. Take a look at how they've implemented `Option`. The `None` instance is really just `case object None extends Option[Nothing]`.